# Github for Physicists

Tags: resource-recommendations, computational-physics, software, algorithms

I am wondering if there is a platform to which researchers share or publish the code they used in their research. I noticed that many researchers explain their algorithm and math and present the results visually but the actual program they used are not included in their papers.

For example, on page 262 of [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XKJV.jpg), Section 3. Results starts with "We have run our two-dimensional denoising algorithm on graphs and real images." and presents several examples of how noisy images can be restored as cleaner images. However, the article doesn't contain any code they used.

[image: Example of denoising an image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XKJV.jpg): Leonid I. Rudin, Stanley Osher, and Emad Fatemi. Nonlinear total variation based noise removal algorithms. Physica D: Nonlinear Phenomena, 60(1):259 – 268, 1992,

Comment: I did find some material claiming to implement these algorithms by simply searching for that title with "+github" prefixed.  I do not know if it is the code the authors themselves used or a different implementation.   Here is one link : [github](https://github.com/vais-ral/CCPi-Regularisation-Toolkit).  I do not know of any general site - I tend to find code on github myself.

Comment: @StephenG This is really relevant, thank you.

Comment: A lot of image processing algorithms like these are produced via computer, engineering and medical research, and not as often directly by physics research.  I'd recommend a [bilateral filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilateral_filter) worth looking at as well - depending on your application these can be a better choice with the right parameters.  A lot of modern noise reduction techniques employ neural networks trained, sometimes for specific noise types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why one would need a special GitHub for physicists -since usual GitHub serves the purpose quite well. I do agree though that in physics there is a tendency to keep hidden **the code AND the data**. In my opinion, this is a field-specific feature.

For example, in biology the journals often require for the data to be published alongside the manuscript - *either as supplementary materials or deposited to public databases* (in which case one publishes the accession numbers). This way anyone could use this data for reanalysis or further research. The same applies to the computational analysis of the data - it is usually deposited openly in GitHub or the authors' web sites, although there is less enforcement in this respect. In principle, physics journals also allow for publishing data and code as supplementary materials, but it is not required and there is no respective tradition in the community.

There are obvious tradeoffs involved: on the one hand, public access to one's data and code may help popularizing one's research. On the other hand, it opens opportunities for the competitors to use your work to produce and publish new results, possibly even snatching the priority. In some cases one may also want to keep the code secret with the aim of commercializing it.

Comment: OK, so there indeed is a field-specific feature. Thank you for explaining.